# LaTeX template for 3 ring binder tabs

Tags: formatting, templates, xtemplate

I have a three ring binder and it has eight page dividers. On each page divider is a clear slot to enter a tab for the name of the subject.

The tabs are 0.5 inches by 1.5 inches. Is there a way to setup an easy environments for these tabs so I can print out a bunch and quickly customize them?

Also the tabs get folded over to make them double thick this way I can write on both sides of the tab. When I print it out and then fold it over and the name will appear on both sides. Also is it possible to place a box around it so I know where to cut out.

When I print it out and cut it out is should look something like this:

[image]

I'm pretty new to Latex so I apologize for not trying anything myself. But I feel you guys are smart enough here to do something like this in no time.

Comment: Yeah! I agree with the smart part and intelligent too. :-)

Comment: The 'no time' thing sounds like wishful thinking, though...

Comment: No time compared to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple  attempt with `minipages` and `\fbox`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,columnsep=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{bbding}
\newcommand\tab[1]{
\Huge\ScissorRightBrokenBottom\\[-5pt]
{\color{gray!30}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][.5in]{1.5in}%
\color{blue!70!black}\large\bfseries\sffamily
\centering\resizebox{.8\linewidth}{!}{#1}%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][.5in]{1.5in}%
\color{black!70!green}\large\bfseries\sffamily
\centering\resizebox{.8\linewidth}{!}{#1}%
\end{minipage}}}\\}

\begin{document}

\tab{Homework}
\tab{To do}
\tab{Drafts}
\tab{Class notes}
\tab{Something}
\tab{Something long}
\newpage
\tab{Maths}
\tab{History}
\tab{Literature}
\tab{Fly scores}
\tab{Nothing}
\tab{\parbox{\linewidth}{Some that need a very long explanation to remember.}}

\end{document}
```